# Making my own sort method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, methods

So I'm new to programming, and I'm working on Chris Pine's Learn to Program, which teaches Ruby. I'm on chapter 10 trying to make my own method for an array.  I was at a total loss and tried modelling mine off his suggested answer.  After fiddling around, I can't get an output.  I run the program and it simply ends.  I even tried using his code and it's giving me the same problem.

Here's what I have so far.

```
unsorted_array = ['gamma', 'delta', 'beta', 'alpha', 'zeta']
sorted_array = []

def sort some_array 
  recursive_sort(some_array, [])
end


def recursive_sort(unsorted_array, sorted_array) 
  if unsorted_array.length <= 0
    return sorted_array 
  end

  still_unsorted =[]
  smallest = unsorted_array.pop
  sorted_array = []

  unsorted_array.each do |tested_obj|
    if '#{tested_obj}' > smallest
      sorted_array.push(smallest)
    else
      still_unsorted.push(smallest)
      smallest = unsorted_array.pop
    end
  end
    recursive_sort(still_unsorted, sorted_array)
end


puts sort(recursive_sort(unsorted_array, sorted_array))
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: When you call `pop` you are mutating the original array. Is that your intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few observations about your code:

- since `test_obj` is a string, `'#{tested_obj}'` is the same as `#{tested_obj}`, which is the same as `tested_obj`.
- declaring `sorted_array = []` has no effect.  Being a local variable, it is not within the scope of teh method `recursive_sort`.  That method receives an array that it calls `sorted_array`, so you would not want it initialized anyway.
- you don't need to create the new array, `still_unsorted`; simply transfer elements from `unsorted_array` to `sorted_array`.

Below I've fixed and tightened up your code.

```
  def recursive_sort(unsorted_array, sorted_array = []) 
    return sorted_array unless unsorted_array.length > 0
    smallest = unsorted_array.min 
    unsorted_array.each {|e| sorted_array << e if e == smallest}
    unsorted_array.delete(smallest)
    recursive_sort(unsorted_array, sorted_array)
  end

  unsorted_array = ['gamma', 'alpha', 'delta', 'beta', 'gamma', 'alpha', 'zeta']
  p recursive_sort unsorted_array
    #  => ["alpha", "alpha", "beta", "delta", "gamma", "gamma", "zeta"]
```

Here's what's happening:

- by giving the second argument of recursive_sort (`sorted_value`) a default value of `[]` (an empty array), there is no need for the method `sort` you had previously.
- `sorted_array` is returned if sorting is finished (same as `return sorted_array if unsorted_array.length == 0`).
- use [`Enumerable#min`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min) to find the smallest value of the unsorted items (`smallest`).
- add each instance of `smallest` in `unsorted_array` to `sorted_array`.
- delete all instances of `smallest` in `unsorted_array`.
- call the same method again, to remove the next smallest unsorted item, etc.

Note

```
  unsorted_array.each {|e| sorted_array << e if e == smallest}
```

could be expressed in many different ways.  Here's one:

```
  sorted_array += [smallest]*(unsorted_array.count {|e| e == smallest})
```

To see how this works, suppose `smallest = 'alpha'`.  Then

```
  unsorted_array.count {|e| e == 'alpha'} # => 2
```

so the above expression is:

```
  sorted_array += ['alpha']*2
```

which is

```
  sorted_array += ['alpha', 'alpha']
```

which adds two `"alpha"`'s to `sorted_array`.

Comment: Thanks so much Cary, you've been a big help.